# Problema al acceder a wordpress con Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, laravel, wordpress

Instale wordpress en laravel homestead pero a la hora de intentar acceder me da un error, este es mi archivo Homestead.yaml.

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
   - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
   - map: ~/code
     to: /home/vagrant/code

sites:
   - map: web_luvb.test
     to: /home/vagrant/code/web_luvb/public
   - map: wordpress.app
     to: /home/vagrant/code/wordpress/public

databases:
   - homestead
   - wordpress
```

archivo hosts

```
127.0.0.1         wordpress.app
```

Ya intente después de configurar el archivo Homestead.yaml un vagrant provision para que lea de nuevo este archivo pero igual me da error "No se puede acceder a este sitio" la url wordpress.app.

En el papel la configuración es fácil no se que no estoy viendo o dejando de hacer?

Comment: Homestead es realmente sencillo. ¿qué hay en wordpress/public?

Comment: nada, es la primera vez que instalo wordpress usando Homestead agregue el /public al final y igual nada no me da acceso a esa url, hasta e reiniciado la pc haber si es que no a tomado la configuración del archivo host

Comment: Si no hay nada en public, ¿qué pretendes que muestre dicha URL?

Comment: y si quito la ip 127.0.0.1 por la que trae por defecto el archivo Homestead.yalm 192.168.10.10 me dice "url no segura" y esa ip me funciona sin ningún problema para mis proyectos laravel.

Comment: a ok como e visto par de tutoriales que no le agregan ese public y los direcciona a la pagina principal de wordpress de configuración que debería tener entonces esa ruta??

Comment: Creo que estás bastante confundido sobre como funciona Laravel, Homestead y Wordpress, sería bueno que leyeras la documentación. Yo la HE leído y todo eso me funciona sin problemas.